# when i use php why does it always display parts of the code as text?

Tags: php

when i type my php code in a html file, using notepad++ as my text editor,why does it always show some of the code as text on the web page

eg.

```
<?php   echo "hello world";   ?>
```

would output:

"hello world";?>

as text on the web page

why does it do this and how can I stop it?

Comment: Probably you have a double closure in the file: you repeat;?>

Comment: `in a html file` makes it HTML, not PHP. Unless you modified the handler, did you do that?

Comment: @chris85 why doesn't it though as html files allow you to enter php code so why not run it

Comment: Because PHP is run through the PHP process. The PHP process only looks for `.php` files being run by apache or any other extension it is told to look at. The same with CLI when you use `php file.php` the first `php` invokes the PHP processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save your PHP code in a file with .php extension. To execute PHP code, you can call the interpreter from your command line with `php myfile.php` or from a webserver like Apache or nginx.
Your browser *cannot* execute PHP code.

Read more about installing PHP here:
http://php.net/manual/en/install.php

**If you're new to PHP**, I would recommend you to read a good book (unfortunately I can't recommend one). Or if you're more the visual learner, take a look at [The PHP Practioner](https://laracasts.com/series/php-for-beginners) made by Jeffrey Way.